# How do I solve a trig equation over an interval?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, trigonometry, intervals

I have an equation $4\sin^2(θ) = 1+4\cos(θ)$. I need to solve this equation on the interval $0<=θ<2 π$.

How would I use the `Solve` and/or `Reduce` commands to solve this equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Reduce[{4 Sin[θ]^2 == 1 + 4 Cos[θ], 0 <= θ < 2 π}]
 (* θ == π/3 || θ == (5 π)/3 *)

Solve[{4 Sin[θ]^2 == 1 + 4 Cos[θ], 0 <= θ < 2 π}]
 (* {{θ -> π/3},{θ -> (5 π)/3}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept using Solve and gave me much longer solutions.

Comment: you can use `Solve` as well: see the latest edit